# Do all AWS Node.js apps require the cluster module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, cluster-computing, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was following the tutorial [here](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/deploy-nodejs-web-app/), and noticed the index file (**app.js**) of the [example code](https://github.com/awslabs/eb-node-express-sample) is quite different than a usual Express.js application. The code is wrapped inside the cluster module as follows:

```
// Include the cluster module
var cluster = require('cluster');

// Code to run if we're in the master process
if (cluster.isMaster) {

    // Count the machine's CPUs
    var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;

    // Create a worker for each CPU
    for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    // Listen for terminating workers
    cluster.on('exit', function (worker) {

        // Replace the terminated workers
        console.log('Worker ' + worker.id + ' died :(');
        cluster.fork();

    });

// Code to run if we're in a worker process
} else {
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    // the usual code ..
}
```

Is this necessary, or can I just deploy the regular code without the cluster module, like this:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// the usual code ..
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary.  The cluster module is a way to make better use of the machine (virtual or physical) processing capabilities, but it is not necessary just to run on AWS.

Comment: Great, so the second example will work when I bundle it as a zip file, right?

Comment: Assuming you've got node running and do npm install and all the usual stuff, yes.

Comment: I can do those things and run my application locally but I don't know how to do those in AWS. Anyways, hopefully I will figure it out :) Thanks! **P.S.:** Just uploading my regular code with the EB console worked, I didn't even need to npm install. I guess AWS does this automatically.

Comment: You didn't mention before that you were using Elastic Beanstalk.  EB is AWS's implementation of what's called Platform-as-a-Service, which means it will provide you all the infrastructure for your application code and run some standard processes based on your app type (in this case, running npm install as a post-deployment step).

Comment: Ohh, I see. So I can skip EB, and use EC2 and run those commands myself? OK, now I see the point of EB :)

Comment: Yep. EB is a convenience.  Not all apps need/ should use it.

Comment: The cluster module is part of **Node.js**. I was confused as well. Read this article: https://dev.to/acanimal/understanding-the-nodejs-cluster-module-14-2bi